# Overriding jquery ui after addClass

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a div which contains a list.

Its CSS:

```
#ResultsText  
{  
  color: #696969;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

In the JS file:

```
$("li.ResultParagraph").mouseover(function () {
  $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
});

$('.ui-state-hover').css("font-weight", "normal");
```

but still I see the hover text in bold.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include some HTML or even better created a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Look here - http://jsfiddle.net/toy4fun/U5Bn9/2 Does'nt seems to work like in the real site.

Comment: [Hows this](http://jsfiddle.net/U5Bn9/1/) I just added the Smoothness theme CSS from jQuery UI - `font-weight` seems to look "normal" to me ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see the code change you have done....

Comment: I didnt change any code - i just added the jQuery CSS theme

Comment: I have it in my default.aspx page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do like this(or switch **"bold"** with **"normal"**)

```
$("li.ResultParagraph").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover").css("font-weight", "bold");
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover").css("font-weight", "normal");
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/U5Bn9/3/)